# Bro: Disable ALL log generation

Tags: file, logging, network-analysis, bro

I created a bro script, with the objective of extract all files for all posible protocols from a pcap file. But I dont want to write all logs. Bro create a log file for each protocol. Example: 'http.log', 'smtp.log', etc. Even a 'weird.log' is generated. My pcap files are large (20gb), so, each log file contains over 30mb of information. This log generation reduce the performance of the file extraction.
I can disable the 'conn.log' with the line `Log::disable_stream(Conn::LOG)` but, what about all protocol logging??
This is my script

```
@load base/files/extract

event bro_init()
    {
        Log::disable_stream(Conn::LOG);

    }

event file_sniff(f: fa_file, meta: fa_metadata)
    {
    local ext = "";

    if ( meta?$mime_type )
        ext = split_string(meta$mime_type, /\//)[1];
    local fname = fmt("%s-%s.%s", f$source, f$id, ext);
    Files::add_analyzer(f, Files::ANALYZER_EXTRACT, [$extract_filename=fname]);
    }
```

Comment: Does running Bro in *bare* mode help? That is, try passing `-b` on the command line.

Comment: The docs says: The bare mode loads only the minimum number of scripts to retain operability and leaves the burden of loading required scripts to the script being run. When i run bro with this params it does not do anything. Even a print call in the first line of the event file_sniff. What do this really mean??

Comment: Bare nose doesn't load any scripts. If you need file extraction, then you have to do so manually by passing it on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `none` writer like this:

```
bro -r packets.pcap Log::default_writer=Log::WRITER_NONE
```

I'm not totally convinced that writing these logs is harming your performance in any real way though.  Typically, writing the files to disk is what causes the biggest overhead.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to turn off whatever logging's been turned on (prior to `bro_init`), without having to know which stream IDs are relevant:

```
event bro_init()
{
   # We don't want any output other than from this script.
   for (id in Log::active_streams)
       Log::disable_stream(id);
}
```

This construct makes me twitch a little about modifying a table while iterating over it, but it seems to work and I can't actually find any way to peek at one key from a table without doing an iteration.  I suppose one could write

```
event bro_init()
{
    while (|Log::active_streams|) {
        for (id in Log::active_streams) {
            Log::disable_stream(id);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

but that's hideous and I'm not going to use it unless I discover that I have to.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer: it applies to all streams and avoids log-related work once the streams are disabled. If performance doesn't matter, or is not a problem for you, then Seth's answer is the easier one.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this with this line of code in main.bro:

```
    Log::remove_filter(Conn::LOG, "default");
```

Comment: That's too narrow — you're silencing the default filter for conn.log. If there's no other log filter attached to it, this will stop logging conn.log. But it has no effect on other log streams.